# Forgot to use stabilizer with motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, fuel-tank, stability

I forgot to fill my motorcycle tank with stabilizer and now it is way to cold to ride.

Should I still put the stabilizer in it? I read the instructions and it is not recommended to use it if the fuel is a few weeks old.

Comment: Hi Bob, hoping you could award the answer to one of the responders if the issue was resolved.  If not, could you populate the solution you discovered to solve the issue, if the issue is unresolved please let us know and someone will help you out.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Drain the fuel in the tank. Then fill it back up with gas which has stabilizer in it. Once this is accomplished, get the bike started and let it run until fully warmed up. This will ensure all of the old gas has been purged. After this, you should be good until spring.

Answer (score 1):

If the fuel is less than about a month old, you're probably still ok with just pouring in a bunch of stabilizer and warming up the bike to get it well mixed.

If it's a couple months old, you probably want to follow @Paulster2's advice and drain the tank.